# How to write this type of bullet style in LaTeX? (Section Symbol)

Tags: table-of-contents

How to write this type of bullet style in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: please have alook at the approximation below

Comment: I removed the `tables` and `tabulary` tages since I could not see a connection to tables here.

Comment: Pleae clarify what you want to use this for. Is this some kind of chapter/section header or part of a numbered list? Answers will vary depending on the intended use case, therefore please add some background information.

Comment: Thanks the answers was good enough for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a section symbol. It can be obtained in text mode with `\textsection` or simply `\S`, or in math mode with `\mathsection`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textsection \S \(\mathsection\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor, lipsum}


\definecolor{carmine}{rgb}{0.68, 0.0, 0.09}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\color{carmine}\S$\,$\thesection}{1em}{}[]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0em} %left
{0em} %before
{1em} %after/below
\begin{document}

    \section{Introduction}
    This is some regular text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a sepcial reason for adding the red color?