# How to write sections in following format?

Tags: sections-paragraphs

[image]

I am not able to find a function to write this. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Does section numbers had to be in red? If not, see if the following solution is what you looking for: `\renewcommand\thesection{§\arabic{section}}`.

Answer (score 5):

I would use `xcolor` package to define the color you want for the red then `titlesec` package to adjust the section font and the spacing between the section number and the section title.

Here's my final code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{191,3,66}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\bfseries}{\color{myred}{§\arabic{section}}}{0.15cm}{}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Back To Basics!}
\end{document}
```

And here's how it looks:
[image: LaTeX output]

Answer (score 2):

From my other answer here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572492/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor, lipsum}


\definecolor{carmine}{rgb}{0.68, 0.0, 0.09}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\color{carmine}\S$\,$\thesection}{1em}{}[]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0em} %left
{0em} %before
{1em} %after/below
\begin{document}

    \section{Introduction}
    This is some regular text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: With your setup, LaTeX inserts *less whitespace* above a section-level header than below. How might one fix that?